# Converting raw text into csv

Tags: python, r, csv

I have a raw dataset (in plain text). Three sample rows are as follows:

```
S.11*  N. ENGLAND           L      -8'    21-23  u44'
S.18    TAMPA BAY            W     -7     40-7    u49'
S.25    Buffalo                       L      -4'    18-33  o48
```

I want to convert it into a csv file. How can I do so? (I prefer either Python or R)

The csv file should be something like:

```
S, 11, *, N. ENGLAND, L, -8', 21, 23, u44'
S, 18,  , TAMPA BAY, W, -7, 40, 7, u49'
S, 25, ,Buffalo, L, -4', 18-33, o48
```

Comment: What could possibly produce such a monstrosity?

Comment: Well, it's raw data from the NFL...

Comment: If the rest of your data is as inconsistent as your example, I don't think there's any way to convert it to CSV other than manually. Is it possible that there are tab characters between each field? Then it would be much more doable.

Comment: I don't think those are tab characters, but here's the website just to be sure: http://www.goldsheet.com/nflog.php

Comment: How are you getting this data in your text file? It should be simple to split on whitespace, browsing the actual page...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : copy and paste

Comment: Yeah, well, copy-paste is probably a bad way to go...

Comment: Is there any way I can design a program to detect the first white space (which gives the month, day, and asterisk) and then the white space before L and W? Thereafter, the remaining whitespaces are easy to detect.

Comment: If I do so, then things become very straightforward after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module to do part of it, and manually deal with the really messy fields at the beginning.

So, assuming you're using Python 3.x, here's what I mean:

```
import csv

input_filename = 'raw_dataset.txt'
output_filename = 'spreads.csv'

with open(input_filename, 'r', newline='') as infile, \
     open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        new_cols = row[0].split('.')
        if not new_cols[1].endswith('*'):
            new_cols.extend([''])
        else:
            new_cols[1] = new_cols[1][:-1]
            new_cols.extend(['*'])
        row = new_cols + row[1:]
        #print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Contents of csv output file produced:

```
S,11,*,N.,ENGLAND,L,-8',21-23,u44'
S,18,,TAMPA,BAY,W,-7,40-7,u49'
S,25,,Buffalo,L,-4',18-33,o48
O,02,,L.,ANGELES,L,-9',13-17,u43'
O,06,*,San,Francisco,W,-3',33-21,o43'
O,17,*,N.Y.,JETS,W,-7',28-3,u46
O,23,*,SEATTLE-ot,L,-1',6-6,u43'
O,30,,Carolina,L,+2',20-30,o46
N,06,,Bye
N,13,,S.,FRAN.,L,-13',23-20,u47
N,20,,Minnesota,L,+2,24-30,o40
N,27,,Atlanta,L,+4,19-38,o49'
D,04,,WASH.,W,-2',31-23,o48'
D,11,,Miami,L,-2,23-26,o44
D,18,,N.,ORLEANS,L,-3,41-48,o48'
D,24,,Seattle,W,+8,34-31,o43'
J,01,,Los,Angeles,W,-7,44-6,o39'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it splits Los Angeles (and other teams) into two cells. But I think I can use find and replace to solve it.

Comment: You might be able to deal with them simply by checking the final length of the row. There will be  8 elements in those that don't have names with embedded spaces in them, and 9 (or more) for any that do. Those could then be shortened by merging row elements together until it's the right length.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that. Still waking up...

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source of the webpage that you linked to, http://www.goldsheet.com/nflog.php, you'll see that each line of data is enclosed in a `<p>` element, and there is a `<span>` containing spaces between each field. So the source looks like this (line breaks added by me for clarity):

```
<p>
S.11*
<span>&#160;&#160;</span>
N. ENGLAND
<span>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
L
<span>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
-8'
<span>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</span>
21-23
<span>&#160;&#160;</span>
u44'
</p>
```

This means that in the HTML source, you can tell the difference between spaces separating fields and the spaces in city names, which solves the biggest problem with importing this data. So the best strategy is probably to parse the data from the page source using something like lxml in Python. After you get each field, you'll need to do some post-processing to split things like the "*" in the first field into a separate column as you have specified. Then you can easily export to csv from Python.

However, the bigger problem is that this data was almost certainly generated by typing it in manually, which means you're very likely to run into subtle inconsistencies in the data over time. As you fix more and more of these, your parsing code will become burdened with special cases. So you should consider whether what you want to do is worth the effort of maintaining such a mess of code.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll do as you say, but I'll fix the special cases manually.

Answer (score 1):

I used the first 8 lines of data dor testing. Line 9 was a Bye and I assume you want to handle those differently. If not then post problem-construction code that is more thorough in illustrating edge cases. This matches pattern of (letter.period.2nums)(space|asterisk)(spaces)(letters.periods,dashes up to 15 in length) and inserts commas before reading.

```
read.table(text=sub(
  patt= "^([[:alpha:]]\\.[0-9]{2})([ *])([ ]{1,5})([a-zA-Z .-]{3,15})([ ])", 
  repl= "\\1,\\2,\\4,",
  dat[1:8]) ,
 sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,quote="\"")
    V1 V2              V3                                     V4
1 S.11  * N. ENGLAND                   L      -8'    21-23  u44'
2 S.18    TAMPA BAY                    W     -7     40-7    u49'
3 S.25    Buffalo                       L      -4'    18-33  o48
4 O.02    L. ANGELES                   L      -9'    13-17  u43'
5 O.06  * San Francisco                 W     -3'    33-21  o43'
6 O.17  * N.Y. JETS                     W     -7'    28-3    u46
7 O.23  * SEATTLE-ot                 L      -1'    6-6      u43'
8 O.30    Carolina                      L      +2'    20-30  o46
```

This creates the `dat` item:

```
dat <- readLines( textConnection("S.11*  N. ENGLAND           L      -8'    21-23  u44'
S.18    TAMPA BAY            W     -7     40-7    u49'
S.25    Buffalo                       L      -4'    18-33  o48
O.02    L. ANGELES             L      -9'    13-17  u43'
O.06*  San Francisco             W     -3'    33-21  o43'
O.17*  N.Y. JETS                  W     -7'    28-3    u46
O.23*  SEATTLE-ot              L      -1'    6-6      u43'
O.30    Carolina                      L      +2'    20-30  o46
N.06    Bye
N.13    S. FRAN.                    L      -13'   23-20  u47
N.20    Minnesota                   L      +2    24-30  o40
N.27    Atlanta                        L      +4    19-38  o49'
D.04    WASH.                       W     -2'    31-23  o48'
D.11    Miami                         L      -2     23-26  o44
D.18    N. ORLEANS            L      -3     41-48  o48'
D.24    Seattle                         W     +8    34-31  o43'
J.01     Los Angeles                W     -7     44-6    o39'"))
```

And the last step of parsing the trailing material might be done with another call to read.table, this time with just the default whitespace separator. If you needed to do a line by line parsing, you could also use the `scan`-function:

```
> read.table(text=dat2$V4)
  V1  V2    V3   V4
1  L -8' 21-23 u44'
2  W  -7  40-7 u49'
3  L -4' 18-33  o48
4  L -9' 13-17 u43'
5  W -3' 33-21 o43'
6  W -7'  28-3  u46
7  L -1'   6-6 u43'
8  L +2' 20-30  o46
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds helpful! Can you include the code in which you used to enter the data into R?

Comment: You can probably read the non-Bye lines with regular `read.table()`.